# Worksheet and containing cells supposedly empty while they do have values

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I have an excel file with data I need to extract. The actual file I wish to do this with is quite big and holds a huge amount of data. However, when I started using interop code as I found it online, I found I kept getting nullpointer exceptions. 
Hence, I created a very simple file where I entered some very simple data (1a, 2b, 3c, etc) in the first cells on a singular sheet. When I tried printing that data in a console application, I still get nullpointers. In the code I pasted below I will put comments what exactly end up being null.

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong that makes interop completely miss the fact there is, in fact, data in the cells. I can easily get the name from the sheets in the file, but am completely unable to access any of the cells.

If it helps, I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 and the most recent Excel version from Office 365. The file itself is an xslx file.

I have tried googling this issue but came across a slew of people who are trying to detect empty cells in excel, which is almost the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do. When I did find a more relevant issue, the given solution did nothing for me (such as "activating" the sheet). I suspect there's something I'm missing or not understanding about Interop or Excel, but have no idea what to look for anymore.

```
public Excel(string path, int sheet) {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[++sheet] as Worksheet;
            Console.WriteLine(ws.Name); //Prints the correct sheet name
            range = ws.UsedRange;
            Console.WriteLine(range.Count); //Prints 0
            var cell = ws.Cells[1,1] as Range;
            var cellValue = cell.Value2; //Nullpointer due to cell being null
            Console.WriteLine(cellValue.ToString());
}
```

I expect to be able to access cell content, both numeric and string values. However, I'm getting a whole lot of nothing, or null, if you want to get technical.

EDIT: Through some further testing I have determined that ws.Cells does return a com object, but becomes null when I attempt to use an index to get a specific cell from it, as if it contains no cells.

```
var cell = ws.Cells[1,1] as Range; //Is null
var cell2 = ws.Cells[1,1]; //Is null
var cell3 = ws.Cells as Range; //returns com object
var test = cell3[0, 0]; //Test is null
```

Comment: I do not see any problem with the line you have mentioned, if object ws is not null then ws.Cells should return a Range. However, if the Cell 1,1 is empty then cell.Value2 will be Null (not cell but Value2), so cellvalue.ToString() might throw Null Exception, but not the line you have mentioned. Check your code once again.

Comment: ws is definitely not null, as it prints out the name perfectly. Using debug mode, I can see that var cell = null through debug mode, despite ws.Cells not returning null. I have done some further testing (will paste as an edit in my question) and determined that ws.Cells does return a com object, but it becomes null as soon as I attempt to index it.

Answer (score 0):

As example, You need to specify range precisely :

```
var col2 = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns["I:I", Type.Missing];

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range item in col2.Cells)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(item.Value) != null)
                {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(item.Value));
                }
                else
                {
                  //do something with null
                  return;
                }
            }
```